# Elasticsearch, how to perform exact match after applying standard analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to do exact matching but it's too limiting because it would not match "foo" against "Foo" etc.

I wonder if there's a way of testing equality after applying an analyzer (e.g. standard analyzer).

```
query: foo strike
document1: Foo strike!  # I want to match because they are equal after analyzing
document2: foo strike back # I do not want to match because "back" is not present in the query
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment from OP on my post, updating my answer.

### Mapping with custom analyzer

```
{
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            }
        },
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

### Search Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : {
                "query" : "Foo strike",
                "operator" : "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index your sample doc and check the tokens generated by these docs

http://{{es_hostname}}:{{es_port}}/{{es_index}}/_analyze --> analyze api

```
{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "foo strike back"
}
```

### Tokens

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "foo",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 3,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "strike",
        "start_offset": 4,
        "end_offset": 10,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "back",
        "start_offset": 11,
        "end_offset": 15,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 2
    }
]
```

}

```
{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "Foo strike!"
}
```

### Tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "Foo", --> Notice these tokens are case-sensitives
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "strike",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Now Using my above search query I get just one documents**

Search endpoint :- http://{{es_hostname}}:{{es_port}}/{{es_index}}/_search

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.9534808,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "59479620",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.9534808,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Foo strike!"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I want the second doc not to match.. (because of the additional 'back')

Comment: @eugene, updated my answer, please have a look and now I get just first doc in search result.

Comment: I guess my question was hard to understand, I wanted to match first doc but not second doc for a given query `foo strike`